Аттрибут controls тега video занимает часть высоты видео в мобильной версии
Такая проблема возникла: есть видео с определенной высотой - оно полностью прилегает к кнопке под ним, но когда включаешь видео, появляется аттрибут controls, занимая низ видео, потом скрывается, но видео становится меньше по высоте, а между самим видео и кнопкой появляется зазор. То есть этот аттрибут занимает часть высоты видео. Как сделать так, чтобы видео всегда было одной высоты (как в компьютерной версии)?

Нет, дефолтный плеер хрома, тогда попробую посмотреть, что у него там заложено. Спасибо.

По-видимому, у контроля есть нижний паддинг, который и дает отступ. Не знаю, правда, как его убрать.

А там получается, что полоса контроля идет как инпут, у которого есть этот паддинг, самого инпута в html-размтеке нет. Мне назначить !important для тега видео?

Что бы взаимодействовать с частями controls нужны особые классы прописывать, которые через инструменты разработчика не видны. Недавно стилизовал плеер, это та ещё морока
